# Trouble selecting records based on date in python/pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column in my dataframe df_events called 'Program Date Time.' I've successfully created separate columns for EventDate and EventTime based on this using df_events.ProgramDateTime.dt.date and df_events.ProgramDateTime.dt.time.

My problem occurs when I try to select records between two dates. I seem to run into all kinds of type errors whatever I try.

I'm a relatively new Python/pandas user, just recently familiar with dataframes. I'm using Python3.7.

I have tried using strptime and even just trying to select records based on the original column ProgramDateTime.

I'm also writing this code in Sublime Text

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from datetime import datetime


File_Path = 'path'
Event_csv = 'file.csv'

df_event = pd.read_csv(File_Path+Event_csv)

# Indicate analysis period
StartDate = datetime.strptime('2018-08-08', '%Y-%m-%d')
EndDate = datetime.strptime('2019-07-01', '%Y-%m-%d')


# Change appropriate column in Events dataframe to make sure in Datetime format.
df_event['ProgramDateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_event['ProgramDateTime'])

#Create separate columns for Event Date and Time in dataframe
df_event['EventDate'], df_event['EventTime'] = df_event.ProgramDateTime.dt.date, df_event.ProgramDateTime.dt.time

# Create dataframe of programs occurring only during analysis period
df_event_ap = df_event[df_event['EventDate']>=StartDate and df_event['EventDate']<=EndDate]

print(df_event_ap.dtypes)
print(df_even_ap.head(11))
```

I expect to see a new dataframe, df_events_ap, containing only those records that are between StartDate and EndDate.

Instead, the problem happens just as Python's supposed to select the records (the code underneath the last comment (#) line.)

I get this error:

> TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date

Comment: Could you please edit your question, so that easy to read your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that I can spot is your `df_event['EventDate']`. This needs to be once again converted into datetime format:

```
df_event['EventDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_event['EventDate'])
```

Then do:

```
from datetime import datetime

StartDate = datetime.strptime('2018-08-08', '%Y-%m-%d')
EndDate = datetime.strptime('2019-07-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Now that `StartDate`, `EndDate` and `df_event['EventDate']` are all in the same format, you have to do:

```
df_event_ap = df_event[(df_event['EventDate']>=StartDate) & (df_event['EventDate']<=EndDate)]
```

You will now get your both outputs:

Output for first print statement:

```
print(df_event_ap.dtypes)
ProgramDateTime    datetime64[ns]
EventDate          datetime64[ns]
EventTime                  object
dtype: object
```

Output for second print statement:

```
print(df_event_ap.head(11))
      ProgramDateTime  EventDate EventTime
0 2018-12-20 12:46:52 2018-12-20  12:46:52
2 2018-12-25 12:46:52 2018-12-25  12:46:52
4 2018-11-20 12:46:52 2018-11-20  12:46:52
5 2018-12-10 12:46:52 2018-12-10  12:46:52
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. :) Please mark the answer as accepted as it can help others in future. Thank you.